# selenium python set_page_load_timeout Message: Not a Number

Tags: python, selenium

I use selenium to start firefox and set the timeout. My code is here:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
t = 60
print(type(t))
driver.set_page_load_timeout(t)
try:
    driver.get("http://www.taobao.com")
except TimeoutException:
    driver.execute_script('window.stop()')
```

And I got the bug:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\PythonTest\webdriver\test.py", line 64, in <module>
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  File "D:\software\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 691, in implicitly_wait
    'implicit': int(float(time_to_wait) * 1000)})
  File "D:\software\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\software\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Not a Number
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: blockcode, added tag

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, I fixed it by updating GeckoDriver and Firefox to the latest versions.