# Python Selenium driver.implicitly_wait(30)

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

We are using VM for the development and Jenkins as a suite. this morning we had a problem with a Selenium test that never happened before. Before I paste the code, it's important to know that the selenium test works on my machine but fails on Jenkins.. (And that it has been working for month)

```
class Remote(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://developer.intuit.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
```

Here is the code that is causing this bug :

```
ERROR: test_sl_front (__main__.SlFront)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scripts/test-sl/sl-front.py", line 160, in setUp
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 778, in implicitly_wait
    'implicit': int(float(time_to_wait) * 1000)})
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: timeouts
```

It is very weird since everything worked fine yesterday and the day before that. 
I tried to remove the ".Firefox()" thinking it might be related to the problem but nothing changed.

The problem is caused by "self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)" which has been used for months. 
We are using the following command line to start this test during the Jenkin's build.

```
export DISPLAY=:99
python ./scripts/test-sl/sl-front.py
```

Comment: have you upgraded firefox, firefoxdriver, or webdriver?

Comment: nothing has been upgraded those past weeks on the server.

Comment: could you mentioned you web-driver, Firefox and gecko-driver version.

Comment: One more query -  When you tried to execute your python script from Jenkins first time, then it failed. ??  Without Jenkins it is running fine till now ???

Comment: to know firefox version from the VM I try to do "firefox -v" but I get : 
"The program 'firefox' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install firefox". I'm sorry if I'm doing an obvious mistake but I'm pretty new to VM/Server

Comment: @GaurangShah the weird thing about the version is that nobody changed anything or updated anything on the server. The problem happened without any change in the code or in the version..

Comment: even browser, are you 100% sure that auto upgrade on the browser was turned off ??

Comment: not so sure after a bit of research. I checked firefox and selenium version : 
Firefox -> 56.0, selenium webdrive -> 3.4.3.
could those version generate a problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium python set_page_load_timeout Message: Not a Number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42976167/608639).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem using `webdriver.Firefox()` with `driver.implicitly_wait(IMPLICIT_WAIT)` and solved it by installing a new version of geckodriver Version 0.19.0 (I had a version from June 2017 before).

Download geckodriver from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.

My configuration:

- Firefox 56.0
- Selenium Version: 3.4.3

Check the version of geckodriver in shell:

```
$ geckodriver -V
geckodriver 0.19.0
```

By default selenium will use the firefox version that's in your path. To change to another version use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary(firefox_path='your firefox path', log_file='your logfile path')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

[Docs for selenium webdriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver)