# Selenium, Python and InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: value must be a non-negative integer

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, arm, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

A Python script I have been using for the last several months broke today. The script monitors a modem for incoming calls and files FTC Do Not Call complaints. The error is *`InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: value must be a non-negative integer`* when calling *`implicitly_wait`*.

I found similar [reports for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46541636/608639), but I have not found one for Chrome. The machine is fully patched, so there is nothing to update like in the Firefox reports.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

---

Here is the script:

```
$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import selenium
import os.path

from packaging import version
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def get_chrome():
    if os.path.isfile('/usr/bin/chromium-browser'):
        return '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
    elif os.path.isfile('/usr/bin/chromium'):
        return '/usr/bin/chromium'
    elif os.path.isfile('/usr/bin/chrome'):
        return '/usr/bin/chrome'
    elif os.path.isfile('/usr/bin/google-chrome'):
        return '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
    else:
        return None

def main():
    opts = Options()
    opts.binary_location = get_chrome()
    opts.add_argument('--headless')
    opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
    driver.maximize_window()

    agent = driver.execute_script('return navigator.userAgent')
    driver.get("https://complaints.donotcall.gov/complaint/complaintcheck.aspx")
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the exception:

```
$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 35, in main
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 793, in implicitly_wait
    'implicit': int(float(time_to_wait) * 1000)})
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: value must be a non-negative integer
  (Session info: headless chrome=75.0.3770.90)
```

---

Here is the Selenium function from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py`:

```
# Timeouts
def implicitly_wait(self, time_to_wait):
    """
    Sets a sticky timeout to implicitly wait for an element to be found,
       or a command to complete. This method only needs to be called one
       time per session. To set the timeout for calls to
       execute_async_script, see set_script_timeout.

    :Args:
     - time_to_wait: Amount of time to wait (in seconds)

    :Usage:
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    """
    if self.w3c:
        self.execute(Command.SET_TIMEOUTS, {
            'implicit': int(float(time_to_wait) * 1000)})
    else:
        self.execute(Command.IMPLICIT_WAIT, {
            'ms': float(time_to_wait) * 1000})
```

---

Here are the specs. The machine is an ARM dev-board [Tritium H3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D4L7GXZ).

```
$ lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
...

$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8

$ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 75.0.3770.90 Built on Ubuntu

$ apt-cache show python3-selenium
Package: python3-selenium
Architecture: all
Version: 3.8.0+dfsg1-3
...

$ apt-cache show chromium-chromedriver
Package: chromium-chromedriver
Architecture: armhf
Version: 75.0.3770.90-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
...
```

Comment: Now open in the Ubuntu issue tracker: [Issue 1833448, InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: value must be a non-negative integer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-selenium/+bug/1833448).

Comment: update selenium using pip.  your version is very old and not compatible with Chrome 75+

Comment: Thanks @Corey. Would you happen to know the minimum version required for Selenium? I can add it to the bug report. `pip` is banned from production machines because of bug reports like [Issue 5247](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247). The pip maintainers cannot be trusted, and I don't have enough Python experience to fix their mistakes.

Comment: Use the latest selenium (currently 3.141.0).  you can also take the source package and  `python setup.py install`.

Comment: call `implicitly_wait()` before the `get()`.  Implicit Waits are different from `WebDriverWait` or sleep()...  You set the value once for the life of the webdriver and it affects waiting on elements for subsequent page loads..  calling it right before quit() isn't actually waiting on anything.