# Facing Chrome driver issue while running selenium script on Linux server

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing issue while running selenium scripts on linux server . Issue is about chrome driver .

Tried to run selenium script on linux server

facing issue in WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() step.

Comment: my error is :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.

Comment: That is suggesting that there is no executable. Is the correct executable located in the appium > chromdriver node module directory? Executable would be like that seen here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.25/

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here is an example of a Selenium [MCVE with error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56672936/608639).

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022224

You need to download the chrome driver and set property:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Download chrome driver from here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: I added this still same error , any issue about guava jar file version ? I am using 25.0

Comment: can you share your code where you're setting the property and where the executable driver is located?

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: my executable driver is located in /usr/bin folder on linux server and i am giving the same path . What can be the issue ?

Comment: I am using below : Google Chrome 75.0.3770.100
ChromeDriver 2.10.267518
Selenium - 3.14

Comment: Add the file format as well: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver.exe");

Comment: Try to put your chromedriver in another location such as desktop and try the absolute path to the driver

Comment: I am trying this on linux server , windows is running fine . Linux will have System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver"