# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: value must be a non-negative integer with ChromeDriver and Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on selenium (3.5.0),Python 3.6.8
i wanted to test simple code that is written below

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
sleep(6)
driver.close()
```

but it is throwing an error i.e 
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: value must be a non-negative integer`
I am not getting where i went wrong

I found similar issue raised by someone in this platform but my problem didn't get solved
please help me in this regard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium, Python and InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: value must be a non-negative integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56672936/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: value must be a non-negative integer
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Presumably you are using the latest *chromedriver=77.0*
- Presumably you are using *chrome= 77.0*.
- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.6.8* which is ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.6.8* , *ChromeDriver v77.0* and the *Chrome Browser v77.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v77.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 77.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v77.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: nice explanation

Comment: *"If your base Web Client version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of Web Client."* - Not everyone can install random packages on their machines or client machines. Some organizations have governance and must follow policies and procedures.

Comment: @jww Agreed. However _Automation Testing_ is all together different art and the _test beds_ needs to be configured optimally to garner the expected ROI.

Comment: @jww you can always downgrade to compatible versions...   see [version-selection](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection)